# Continuous random variables problem

Tags: probability

Let $X$ be a uniform random variable defined on $(0,1)$.

For which function $g:(0,1) \rightarrow \mathbb R $ do  we have $Y=g(X) \sim {\rm Exp} (1)$?

In other words, $g$ transforms the uniform random variable $X$ into a exponential random variable $g(X)$.
If $g(X)$ was an exponential random variable with parameter $1$, we would have
$${\rm P}(g(X)\le y)=1-e^{-y}$$
but I don't know how to continue.

Answer (score 1):

1. Compute $F_g(x) = \mathbb{P}[g(X) \le x]$ as you did correctly
2. Find it's functional inverse, $F^{-1}_g(x)$. This is the function you need.

For the second step, exchange $x,y$ in your function from (1) and solve for $y$, i.e.
$$
x = 1 - e^{-y}
$$
and solve for $y$...